# Macro with dimension parameters

Tags: tex-core

I've tried the following

```tex
\newdimen\fooDimen
\fooDimen=10.0pt
\newdimen\barDimen
\barDimen=20.0pt
 
\newcommand{\fooCommand}{2}{%
\ifdim#1 < #2
\typeout{Test}
\fi
}
 
\begin{document}
\fooCommand{\fooDimen}{\barDimen}
\end{document}
```

but I get

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   ##
l.18 \ifdim#
            1 < #2
```

What's wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `\newcommand{\fooCommand}[2]{...}` instead. The number of arguments is provided in `[]`. Also you should comment out the line ending after `\typeout{Test}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `\documentclass{article}` and report the file with line numbers for reference:

```
  1 \documentclass{article}
  2 \newdimen\fooDimen
  3 \fooDimen=10.0pt
  4 \newdimen\barDimen
  5 \barDimen=20.0pt
  6
  7 \newcommand{\fooCommand}{2}{%
  8 \ifdim#1 < #2
  9 \typeout{Test}
 10 \fi
 11 }
 12
 13 \begin{document}
 14 \fooCommand{\fooDimen}{\barDimen}
 15 \end{document}
```

If I run LaTeX on this document, I get

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   ##
l.8 \ifdim#
           1 < #2
?
```

so you can clearly see that it's not the call of `\fooCommand` that triggers the error, which instead happens when TeX is examining line 8.

Now you should know that TeX makes no interpretation whatsoever of the replacement text when it is defining a new command and just stores it away. However, here the intended replacement text is actually being processed!

And the error message says that the `#` character is out of place: TeX wants to evaluate `\ifdim`, but it finds `#` instead (in the error message it appears doubled to show that the offending token has category code 6). Here no argument replacement is made, because TeX is *not* defining a command.

Where's the problem? You're using the wrong syntax for `\newcommand`: the number of arguments should be in brackets, not in braces. So what you're actually doing is to define `\fooCommand` to stand for `2`. Then the definition has ended and TeX starts to process what comes along.

```
\newcommand{\fooCommand}[2]{%
  \ifdim#1 < #2
    \typeout{Test}%
  \fi
}
```